# Using custom Selenium server on capybara

Tags: testing, selenium, cucumber, bdd, capybara

I'm trying to use capybara and Selenium but with custom server for Selenium, for example I want to route the server to saucelabs.com, is anyone here are have try it before?

Thanks b4

Comment: Do you mean you want to test the website at saucelabs.com?

Answer (score 1):

in your env.rb put

```
Capybara.app_host = "saucelabs.com"
```